# Pygame - pygame.mouse.get_pos problems

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

The problem isn't errors, it's just that i'm trying to get this crosshair image to follow the mouse about the screen, I succeeded but it's leaving a trail of the same image behind it so the screen eventually becomes spammed with the image, heres the code:

```
import sys, pygame;
from pygame.locals import *;
spaceship = ('spaceship.png')
mouse_c = ('crosshair.png')
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
mousec = pygame.image.load(mouse_c).convert_alpha()
space_ship = pygame.image.load(spaceship).convert_alpha()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            print("test1")
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 3:
            print("test3")
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #Here is the mouse following code
    screen.blit(mousec, (pos)) #Setting image to pos of mouse.. atleast I think I am
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has no problem....it is doing what you are telling it.
However for any image drawn a new background is created (along with the image) that is set as the new background it self so the background needs to be erased and set to default before the function  `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.flip()` is called.

more information [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html)

1. So basically all you can do is create a new background by taking a image (800x600) `('background.png')`.
2. Load it:
   `bk = pygame.image.load('background.png').convert_alpha()`
3. Blit it before blitting other moving objects.
   `screen.blit(bk, (0,0))`
   `pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #Here is the mouse following code`
   `screen.blit(mousec, (pos)) #Setting image to pos of mouse`
   `pygame.display.update()`

Adding a background to your game provides the game a complete touch but if you do not want to add it then the simplest thing you can do is fill your screen with a color every time the `while` loop is called.
So just after the while loop starts add this:
`screen.fill(Color("black"))`